# validation for special characters for name except alphabets underscore numbers in jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

I need to validate the name allowing only alphanumerics and underscore but not any other characters in jquery.pls help me.

My code

```
function validateName($name) {
var Name = /^[a-z0-9\_]+$/i.test(value);
if (!NameReg.test($name)) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
}
```

where i am going wrong not cumin to knw.help me pls.

Comment: @NoBBy otherwise the regex expression is correct??? i need to allow alphanumerics and underscore not others

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z_0-9]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Enter only alpha numeric characters.");
```

add above code before .validate() and add class 'alphanumeric' to your html class.

Comment: @Nirmala you can place this code in the page you validating or place in .js file and include it, note that it is coded with jquery

Comment: sorry i am not able to get result as u suggested